# How to download a file to memory casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a beginner programmer in casperjs and I'm trying to download files from the webpage and save on memory. I'm able to save to a TEMP folder, just wondering if theres a better way.

```
function downloadfile(newUrl){
   var fileExt = newUrl.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
   var path = 'C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/' + fileExt;
   casper.download(newUrl, path);
}
```

Comment: What is your issue with your code?

Comment: I've created a web crawler to download files off each link, its currently going into my temp folder. But I noticed the speed is a lot slower. I'm hoping to save the files to memory to increase the speed of the crawler.

Comment: So, you do not have particular things to do. Just tell casper to get the page, then do what you want: docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file through a custom POST request with CasperJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114521/how-to-download-a-file-through-a-custom-post-request-with-casperjs)