# Unable to download file with CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to download a file with CasperJS. If using browser, the download begins when user clicks a button and the response headers look like this:
[image]

I have tried these two methods with no luck:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26334034

With this approach, the code block inside the if-statement is never executed. If I remove the condition, a bunch of resources are being saved, such as css files and so on. So the event listener is working, but for some reason not triggering when I use CasperJs click function to click the button that should start the download.

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/30122021/692695

File.csv is saved but it's the web sites sourcecode, not the csv-file I get when I click the button on the website.

All of my code:

```
'use strict';

var utils = require('utils');

var casper = require('casper').create({
    //verbose: true,
    //logLevel: "debug",
    clientScripts: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
});

function writeHtml(filename) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var content = casper.getHTML();
    fs.write(filename, content, 'w');
}

function getUrl() {
  var url;
  url = $('.tableofcontent_link:contains("Väestö työmarkkina-aseman, sukupuolen ja iän mukaan")').parent().attr('href');
  return url;
}

casper.selectOptionByValue = function(selector, valueToMatch){
    this.evaluate(function(selector, valueToMatch){
        var select = document.querySelector(selector),
            found = false;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(select.children, function(opt, i){
            if (!found && opt.value.indexOf(valueToMatch) !== -1) {
                select.selectedIndex = i;
                found = true;
            }
        });
        // dispatch change event in case there is some kind of validation
        var evt = document.createEvent("UIEvents"); // or "HTMLEvents"
        evt.initUIEvent("change", true, true);
        select.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }, selector, valueToMatch);
};

var link;
var url = 'http://pxnet2.stat.fi/PXWeb/pxweb/fi/StatFin/StatFin__tym__tyti/?table';
casper.start(url);
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');
casper.then(function () {
    this.echo("Now at: " + this.getCurrentUrl());
    link = 'http://pxnet2.stat.fi' + casper.evaluate(getUrl);
});
casper.then(function () {
    this.open(link);
});
casper.then(function() {
  this.echo("Now at: " + this.getCurrentUrl());
  // Select all data for each item
  casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_VariableSelectorValueSelectRepeater_ctl01_VariableValueSelect_VariableValueSelect_SelectAllButton');
  casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_VariableSelectorValueSelectRepeater_ctl02_VariableValueSelect_VariableValueSelect_SelectAllButton');
  casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_VariableSelectorValueSelectRepeater_ctl03_VariableValueSelect_VariableValueSelect_SelectAllButton');
  casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_VariableSelectorValueSelectRepeater_ctl04_VariableValueSelect_VariableValueSelect_SelectAllButton');
  casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_VariableSelectorValueSelectRepeater_ctl05_VariableValueSelect_VariableValueSelect_SelectAllButton');
});
casper.then(function() {
  // casper.selectOptionByValue('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_OutputFormats_OutputFormats_OutputFormatDropDownList',
  // 'FileTypeExcelX');

  // Select the format of the file from the select option list at the bottom
  casper.selectOptionByValue('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_OutputFormats_OutputFormats_OutputFormatDropDownList',
  'FileTypeCsvWithHeadingAndSemiColon');
});
casper.then(function () {
    // just for debugging
    writeHtml('page1.html');
});
casper.then(function() {
  //casper.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_VariableSelector1_VariableSelector1_ButtonViewTable');
});
casper.then(function() {
  // FIRST ATTEMPT TO LOAD THE DATA TO a file called file.csv
  var formData = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return $('form#aspnetForm').serialize();
  });
  //this.echo("Params: " + formData);
  var targetFile = 'file.csv';
  casper.download(link, targetFile, 'POST', formData);
});
casper.then(function () {
    // just for debugging
    writeHtml('page2.html');
});

// SECCOND ATTEMPT TO LOAD THE DATA TO a file called stats.csv
casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
  if ((resource.url.indexOf('tyti_001') !== -1) ) {
    this.echo(resource.url);
    var file;
    file = "stats.csv";
    try {
      this.echo("Attempting to download file " + file);
      var fs = require('fs');
      casper.download(resource.url, fs.workingDirectory + '/' + file);
    } catch (e) {
      this.echo(e);
    }
  }
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.echo('End').exit();
});
```

And my package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
      "test": "dotest"
    },
    "pre-commit": ["test"],
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "pre-commit": "^1.2.2"
    }
}
```

Explanation of the code:
First visit this page: http://pxnet2.stat.fi/PXWeb/pxweb/fi/StatFin/StatFin__tym__tyti/statfin_tyti_pxt_001.px/?rxid=bd4d5dc1-358d-407e-ae47-13266b79bfd0
There, dynamically pick a specified link and move there.
Select all data by clicking the V-shapen icon (look at the attached screenshot) and then select the format of the file.

[image: Screenshot with annotations]

Comment: It's difficult to tell what the cause of the problem is without linking to the file in question. There are a variety of possibilities. One possibility is that the website could be blocking the CasperJS/PhantomJS user-agent. You can change that using: [`casper.userAgent()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#useragent).

Comment: Changing user agent doesn't help. I added all the code and also link to the website casperjs is using to attempt to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue earlier with all versions except phantomjs 2.0.0. I also tried the solutions you shared from SO a year ago and they didn't work as well.
I'm going to assume you're using a phantomjs version other than 2.0.0.
Here's the link to download it
https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

With it, you will have access to onFileDownload method which you can override and use like below

```
casper.page.onFileDownload = function(status){
    console.log('onFileDownload(' + status + ')'); 
    return "newfile.csv";
};
```

onFileDownload will be called whenever a file is downloaded as a result of clicking a button (ajax) or as a result of sequential get/post requests. 
All you have to do is, trigger the click on the button/link that will initiate download.

**Note :** My solution is assuming that everything else (site is not blocking phantomjs and your request headers/cookies are as expected)